# Inverse of matrix and multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I am new to world of matrix, sorry for this basic question I could not figure out:

I have four matrix (one unknown).

Matrix X

```
x <- c(44.412, 0.238, -0.027, 93.128, 0.238, 0.427, -0.193, 0.673, 0.027, 
     -0.193, 0.094, -0.428, 93.128, 0.673, -0.428, 224.099)

X <- matrix(x, ncol = 4 )
```

Matrix B : need to be solved , 1 X 4 (column x nrows), with b1, b2, b3, b4 values

Matrix G

```
g <- c(33.575, 0.080, -0.006, 68.123, 0.080, 0.238, -0.033, 0.468, -0.006, 
-0.033, 0.084, -0.764, 68.123, 0.468, -0.764, 205.144)

G <- matrix(g, ncol = 4)
```

Matrix A

```
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1) # one this case but can be any value 
A <- matrix(a, ncol = 1)
```

Solution:

```
B = inv(X) G A  # inv(X) is inverse of the X matrix multiplied by G and A
```

I did not know how to solve this properly, particularly inverse of the matrix. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You could check `?solve`

Comment: The inverse of a matrix is `solve`.  Matrix multiplication is `%*%`.

Comment: thanks Nick and Ben for solving the problem...I know the question was too basic but that is what my level of knowledge on matrix stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that Nick and Ben are both teachers and have even greater scruples than I do about doing other peoples' homework, but the path to a complete solution was really so glaringly obvious that it didn't make a lot of sense not to tae the next step:

```
B = solve(X) %*% G %*% A 
> B
             [,1]
[1,] -2.622000509
[2,]  7.566857261
[3,] 17.691911600
[4,]  2.318762273
```

The QR method of inversion can be invoked by supplying an identity matrix as the second argument:

```
> qr.solve(G, diag(1,4))
                [,1]             [,2]          [,3]             [,4]
[1,]  0.098084556856 -0.0087200426695 -0.3027373205 -0.0336789016478
[2,] -0.008720042669  4.4473233701790  1.7395207242 -0.0007717410073
[3,] -0.302737320546  1.7395207241703 13.9161591761  0.1483895429511
[4,] -0.033678901648 -0.0007717410073  0.1483895430  0.0166129089935
```

Comment: +1 One should caution the OP that taking the inverse of a matrix is generally not a great idea computationally. If you are fitting a model of some for, using an algorithm based on a decomposition instead of inverting a matrix would be preferred.

Comment: thanks, DWin for the solution...I am really embrassed to ask such a basic question .. @Gavin, can you elaborate your suggestion as answer ...?

Answer (score 3):

A more computationally stable solution is to use `qr` rather than `solve`.

```
method1 <- solve(X) %*% G %*% A
method2 <- qr.coef(qr(X), G) %*% A
stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(method1, method2)))
```

See the examples in `?qr`.

Comment: `library(fortunes)`; `fortune("regression coefficients")`