# How to compute diag(X %*% solve(A) %*% t(X)) efficiently without taking matrix inverse?

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, matrix-inverse

I need the following diagonal:

```
diag(X %*% solve(A) %*% t(X))
```

where `A` is a full rank square matrix, `X` is a rectangular matrix. Both `A` and `X` are sparse.

I know finding the inverse of a matrix is bad unless you really need it. However, I can't see how to rewrite the formula such that `solve(A)` is replaced by `solve` with two arguments, such that a linear system is solved without explicitly inverting. Is that possible?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I will accept but I never do it too soon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps before I really start, I need to mention that if you do

```
diag(X %*% solve(A, t(X)))
```

matrix inverse is avoided. `solve(A, B)` performs LU factorization and uses the resulting triangular matrix factors to solve linear system `A x = B`. If you leave `B` unspecified, it is default to a diagonal matrix hence you will be explicitly computing matrix inverse of `A`.

You should read `?solve` carefully, and possibly many times for hints. It says it is based on `LAPACK` routine [`DGESV`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/d72/dgesv_8f_source.html), where you can find the numerical linear algebra behind the scene.

```
DGESV computes the solution to a real system of linear equations

   A * X = B,

where A is an N-by-N matrix and X and B are N-by-N RHS matrices.

The LU decomposition with partial pivoting and row interchanges is
used to factor A as

  A = P * L * U,

where P is a permutation matrix, L is unit lower triangular, and U is
upper triangular.  The factored form of A is then used to solve the
system of equations A * X = B.
```

The difference between `solve(A, t(X))` and `solve(A) %*% t(X)` is a matter of efficiency. The general matrix multiplication `%*%` in the latter is much more expensive than `solve` itself.

Yet, even if you use `solve(A, t(X))`, you are not on the fastest track, as you have another `%*%`.

Also, as you only want diagonal elements, you waste considerable time in first getting the full matrix. **My answer below will get you on the fastest track.**

I have rewritten everything in LaTeX, and the content is greatly expanded, too, including reference to R implementation. Extra resources are given on QR factorization, Singular Value decomposition and Pivoted Cholesky factorization in the end, in case you find them useful.

---

[image: overview]

[image: chol]

[image: lu]

---

**Extra resources**

In case you are interested in pivoted Cholesky factorization, you can refer to [Compute projection / hat matrix via QR factorization, SVD (and Cholesky factorization?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9071020/4891738). There I also discuss QR factorization and singular value decomposition.

The above link is set in ordinary least square regression context. For weighted least square, you can refer to [Get hat matrix from QR decomposition for weighted least square regression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20562177/4891738).

QR factorization also takes compact form. Should you want to know more on how QR factorization is done and stored, you may refer to [What is "qraux" returned by QR decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38741127/4891738).

These questions and answers all focus on numerical matrix computations. The following gives some statistical application:

- [linear model with `lm()`: how to get prediction variance of sum of predicted values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39337862/4891738)
- [Sampling from multivariate normal distribution with rank-deficient covariance matrix via Pivoted Cholesky Factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35346238/4891738)
- [Boosting `lm()` by a factor of 3, using Cholesky method rather than QR method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38604244/4891738)